# I'm using ThirdWeb to create an app. However I'm getting a babel error that I'm not able to fix

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

The code causing the error is the import line which goes:
 `import { ChainId, ThirdwebProvider } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";`.
This is the error message:

```
./node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/sdk/dist/index.js
SyntaxError: /Users/username/repo/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/sdk/dist/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (15:22749):

-- a lot message in between but not essential--

16 | //# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

Has anyone faced this problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: Are you using a webpack loader?